# ORDER BY , como ordenar monto salariales

Tags: sql

buen dia chicos mi duda es esta pongo la sintaxis con su respectiva order by desc para que me muestre la ganancia de mayor a menor pero me las sigue ordenando aleatoriamente :(

```
SELECT month(s.fInicio)AS [MES],a.Nombre_auto,
   SUM(DATEDIFF(d, dateadd(d, -1, s.fInicio), s.fTermino) * a.Tarifa_Diaria) [GANANCIA]
FROM dbo.Arriendo_Solicitud s
INNER JOIN dbo.Arriendo_Autos a ON a.Patente = s.Patente
GROUP BY month(s.fInicio),a.Nombre_Auto ,a.Tarifa_Diaria
ORDER BY month(s.fInicio),a.Tarifa_Diaria DESC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: fijate el order by, primero te lo ordena por `MES `y luego por `Tarifa_Diaria ` por eso obtienes ese resultado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es que no estás ordenando por el campo que deberías.

```
SELECT month(s.fInicio)AS [MES],a.Nombre_auto,
   SUM(DATEDIFF(d, dateadd(d, -1, s.fInicio), s.fTermino) * a.Tarifa_Diaria) [GANANCIA]
FROM dbo.Arriendo_Solicitud s
INNER JOIN dbo.Arriendo_Autos a ON a.Patente = s.Patente
GROUP BY month(s.fInicio),a.Nombre_Auto ,a.Tarifa_Diaria
ORDER BY SUM(DATEDIFF(d, dateadd(d, -1, s.fInicio), s.fTermino) * a.Tarifa_Diaria) DESC
```

Como no se que motor de base de datos estás usando, te recomiendo ordenar por el campo entero(operaciones incluidas) en vez de por el alias

Answer (score 2):

Solo tienes que colocar la tarifa diaria en el primer lugar y tomara en cuenta el primer campo luego el siguiente así sucesivamente, tu código quedaría así,

```
SELECT month(s.fInicio)AS [MES],a.Nombre_auto,
   SUM(DATEDIFF(d, dateadd(d, -1, s.fInicio), s.fTermino) * a.Tarifa_Diaria) [GANANCIA]
FROM dbo.Arriendo_Solicitud s
INNER JOIN dbo.Arriendo_Autos a ON a.Patente = s.Patente
GROUP BY month(s.fInicio),a.Nombre_Auto ,a.Tarifa_Diaria
ORDER BY month(s.fInicio) ASC,a.Tarifa_Diaria DESC
```

Espero que te funcione